# how to hit controller action from a-usercontrol-ascx using ajax request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

this is the ascx user control , i am trying to do ajax request then hit the controller but i have a problem and error message i can not find this `CreateSubscribe/Create` 404 (Not Found) error message.

any advice

```html
    <input type="text" id="subscribe-form-email" name="email" class="bg-transparent text-small no-margin border-color-medium-dark-gray" placeholder="Enter your email...">
<button id="button-subscribe-newsletter"  type="button" class="btn btn-arrow-small position-absolute border-color-medium-dark-gray">
<i class="fa fa-caret-right no-margin-left"></i></button>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#button-subscribe-newsletter").click(function () {
        debugger
            if ($('#subscribe-form-email').val().length > 0)
            {
                var dataToPost = {
                    subscriberemail: $("#subscribe-form-email").val(),
                }

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'CreateSubscribe/Create',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataToPost),                   
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            $("#Subscribe-Area").hide();
                            $("#Success-Message").show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#Failed-Message").show();
                        }                       
                    },
                    error:function
                        (err)
                    {
                        alert(err.message);
                    }
                });
            }         
        });

</script>
```

this is the controller

```
 public class CreateSubscribeController : Controller
{
    // GET: CreateSubscribe
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string subscriberemail)
    {
        var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "Email",subscriberemail }
        };

        if (SitefinityWebApp.Helpers.SitefinityHelper.CreateSubscriberAndAddToMailingList(MailList.Maillist, subscriberemail))
        {
            SitefinityWebApp.Helpers.SitefinityHelper.SendEmailByTemplate(EmailTemplates.SubscribeEmail, subscriberemail, keys);
            return Json(new { val = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { val = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lets see the controller method as well.

Comment: The issue would appear to be with the URL you're using in the AJAX request. Assuming the controller is configured correctly, try adding a `/`  to the path to base it from the root of the domain: `url: '/CreateSubscribe/Create'`. Better still, use `@Url.Action()` instead of hard-coding

Comment: Ensure your url is correct. Is your webapi deployed under the same domain where  you have webpage with ascx control on it? 404 means that your url is incorrect

Comment: i updated the question with the controller

Comment: You may have a content type problem. You are sending as application/json but your controller is accepting a string.